# Another word for "designated"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, vocabulary

I am in need for a word to mean "designated" but with a stronger undertone of dictated task that one is obliged to perform reluctantly. Thanks. :)

Comment: What have you thought about the synonym list? http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/designate

Comment: Yes I have done the basic googling but none of the words there quite capture what I am intending.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> what about-
>    **[mandated](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mandate)**.
>
> A mandate is like an official command or a go-ahead.

Comment: I think this is the closest thing I can get. It still doesnt sound perfect but I think it will suffice, many thanks.

Comment: @Coldfusion Mandated does not imply reluctance on the part of the designee.  If you really want to stress reluctance, use 'forced'

Answer (score 5):

It's difficult to know without the exact context, but are you looking for a word such as "mandatory" or "compulsory"?

Answer (score 2):

Your description does not well match with the word you venture, so a list of its synonyms is all too unlikely to include such words *[mandate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mandate)* and *[order](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/order)* (links to M-W), which I think are what you seek. Both of these can be used as either verbs or nouns.

Comment: Ordered or forced are the words I would choose

Answer (score 2):

**[TASKED?](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/task)**

a  :  a usually assigned piece of work often to be finished within a certain time

b :  something hard or unpleasant that has to be done

c :  duty, function
:  subjection to adverse criticism :  reprimand —used in the expressions to take, call, or bring to task

Answer (score 2):

This might suit your purpose,

> **ASSIGN** *verb*: assign; 3rd person present: assigns; past tense: assigned; past participle: assigned; gerund or present participle: assigning
>
> **1**. allocate (a job or duty).
>   "Congress assigned the task to the agency"
>
> *synonyms*: allocate, allot, give, set to; charge with, entrust with
>
> "a young doctor was assigned the task"
>
> • appoint (someone) to a particular job, task, or organization.
>   "she has been assigned to a new job"
>
> *synonyms*: appoint to, promote to, delegate to, commission to, post to, co-opt to; select for, choose for, install in; detail to
>
> "she was assigned to a new post"
>
> **2**. designate or set (something) aside for a specific purpose. see Google.com "assign" [Link](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=assign+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 2):

Well,

If this is supposedly an assignment passed down from above and is likely to be unpleasant in some way, then how about using "***delegated***"?

Or if you want to put more authority behind the assigning of the task, you can use "***decreed***".

HTH.